# Mac OS Server Mobile User Account, for Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, mac-osx-server

I need to know whether it is possible or not to mimic the Mobile User Account of Open Directory with a Windows workstation connecting on the Open Directory domain.

The thing is, I need to sync the files on login, keep the files locally for work during login, and then sync the files to the server on logout. I heard the Mobile User Account from OS X Server can provide such functionnality, but would I need a Mac client to achieve that functionnality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly synonymous with the Mobile User Account, with Windows a roaming profile is similar (but has to be treated completely differently). Have you tried looking into setting up roaming profiles?

At my workplace we use roaming profiles and folder redirection for our PCs to connect to our Mac OS X Server.

But yes, if you want the functionality of a mobile user account - using a portable home directory (PHD) from Mac OS X Server it does need to be a Mac on the other end to take full advantage of the features.

Comment: Meh, good answer, but I "need" the PHD functionnality, to lighten the network load. Giganormous files + roaming profiles != cool. Also, we want local working copies, server copies, and (Time Machine) backuped copies.